# Multiple filter conditions for WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, theme-development

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this (really simple) task:

> Get 4 random posts, but only select from the 10 most recent posts.

This works great for the random part, but obviously selects from all the posts:

```
    $query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'post__not_in' =>array($post->ID)
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($query);
```

Basically I want to take the results of one query:

```
    $firstquery = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post__not_in' =>array($post->ID),
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
```

And pass the results into that first one.

Any help would be super appreciated. I've looked at merging them but I think that just give me results from both? Little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run first query las 10 posts, than use [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) PHP function on posts array:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post__not_in' =>array( $post->ID ),
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  if ( $query->post_count > 4 ) {

    $query->posts = array_rand( $query->posts, 4 ); // get 4 random posts

    $query->post_count = 4; // update post count

    // for pagination, if you need it
    $query->max_num_pages = (int) ceil( $query->found_posts / 4 ); 
  }

  // After that loop as usual
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    // loop here

  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: The array_rand function is really neat, thanks! I confess I couldn't get this to work - debug kept complaining about a non-object. Nevertheless I really appreciate the answer! I'm sure I just wasn't implementing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

### This answer is incorrect

...And I couldn't withdraw it after it had been accepted, please see comments.

---

You can use [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to get the newest 10 posts, then grab the ids and feed them to your `WP_Query`'s `post__in` argument.

```
global $post;

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'exclude' => $post->id,
) );

$recent_posts_ids = array();
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ) {
    $recent_posts_ids[] = $recent_post["ID"];
}

$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post__in' => $recent_posts_ids,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```

Comment: Running 2 db queries instead of one with the only purpose to extract 4 elements from an array is something I really would avoid. Moreover you should never name a custom query variable `$wp_query` when in global scope, that will override main query messing up things... cc @jfree

Comment: It is not *incorrect* indeed, it works, just not the best one ;)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, I've changed the accepted answer. It does work perfectly, though, (as you said) so I'll probably keep it for the time being since I couldn't get the other to work.